# how to loop through a database table and select everything with the same "type". Using php and sql

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to loop through all the tables in my database and select everything that has the same type. The following code works expect it only prints out the first entry it finds. For example if someone selects "chicken" to view recipes from it pulls out the first chicken recipe in that the database and thats it. I need it to loop through and get all recipes with type chicken. I have looked up different ways to approach this and none have worked. The for loop I tried using in this one is wrong as well so if anyone has a good approach for this please let me know! Also in my html code all the category's have the same name of "cate" but different values. If that helps.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        $db_server = "server";
        $db_username = "name";
        $db_password = "pass";

        $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $database = "Recipes";

        $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
        if (!$er) {
            print ("Error - Could not select the database");
            exit;
        }
        //take info from search and looks through the database for recipe
        $cate = $_POST['cate'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE type ='$cate'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        for($row=1; $row <=$cate; $row++){
        ?>


        <!-- Prints out the recipe -->
        <table border ="1">
            <tr> <h1>
                    <?php

                    print $row['title'];
                    ?>
                </h1>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p> Ingredients: </p>
                    <?php
                    print $row['num_of_1'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_1'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_1'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_2'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_2'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_2'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_3'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_3'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_3'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_4'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_4'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_4'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_5'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_5'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_5'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_6'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_6'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_6'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_7'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_7'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_7'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_8'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_8'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_8'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_9'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_9'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_9'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    print $row['num_of_10'] . " ";
                    print $row['measure_10'] . " ";
                    print $row['ingredient_10'] . " ";
                    print ("<br />");
                    ?>
                </td>           
                <td>
                    <p> Instructions: </p>
                    <?php
                    print $row['instructions'];
                    print ("<br />");
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

        <p> 
            Like this Recipe? Rate It!
            <input type = "submit" value = "Good Ramen" />
        </p>
        <br />
        <br />

        <p>Add a Comment: </p>
        <textarea name = "comment" rows = "10" cols = "100" > </textarea>
        <br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Add Comment" />
        <br />
        <p> Comments: </p>
        <?php
        $comment_query = ("SELECT *");
        while ($comment_query) {
            date_default_timezone_get('UPC');
            print ($row['username'] . " ");
            print ($row['date_added']);
            print ($row['comment']);
            print ("<br />");
        }
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The FOR loop goes While $row <= $cate.  How is $cate the number of records returned?

Comment: cate is the type of food they want to view so when they select a type, chicken, it returns it returns recipes with that type and then should loop to get all the recipes with that type. cates not a number just a identifier

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be like so:

```
for($row=0; $row < count($row); $row++){
```

Comment: The for loop is not returning anything, I dont think because my php now returns a blank page. However, when I take the for loop out the code works again its just only the one recipe as before.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to say but try to replace the for loop

```
for($row=1; $row <=$cate; $row++){
```

with while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
```

Comment: The while loop skip the first one with correct type and got the second one..but didnt loop through. weird

Answer (score 0):

hello you have to do this 
 `for ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )` and you ll access to your fields like `$row[fields]` the thing is every time theres a row the loop for will run 
 PS : they say that querin a db in a loop its not a good idea